# How to put bash variable in html <img> tag?

Tags: html, bash, gnuplot

I am creating a CGI that allows me to directly see the RAM and CPU consumption of several clusters using a graph generated by gnuplot.

So I have a first web page with a menu listbox in which are located the names of my clusters and a generate button:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="test/html"; charset=UTF-8">
                <title> CLUSTER GRAPH </title>
                <h1> Cluster Graph <font size=3> <a href="Index.sh">[ Index ]</a> </font> </h1>
                <hr size="4" color="blue">
        </head>
<body>

<p> Choose a Cluster and press the button to generate the graph ! </p>'

Cluster_Name=$(cat ClusterFullList.csv | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq)

echo "<form action="script_extract.sh" method="post">"
echo "<select name="CLUSTER">"
echo "$Cluster_Name" | while read CLUSTER; do
        echo " <option value="$CLUSTER">$CLUSTER</option>"
        done
echo "</select>"
        echo"<br><br>"
        echo "<input type="submit" value="Generate">"
echo "</form>"

echo'
</body>
</html> 
'
```

When you click on generate, the graph should appear with a brief summary of the consumption next to it :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "
<html>
    <head>
        <title> CLUSTER GRAPH </title>
        <h1> Cluster Graph <font size=3> <a href="Index.sh">[ Index ]</a></font></h1>
        <hr size="4" color="blue">


        <style>
             hr{
              margin-top: 1%;
             }

             #p1{
               font-size: 18px;
               text-decoration: underline;
               margin-top: -41.8%;
               margin-left: 58.5%;
               margin-bottom: 2%;
             }

             #p2{
               font-size: 14px;
                           margin-top: -2.9%;
               margin-left: 58.5%;
               margin-bottom: 4%;
             }

             #p3{
                           font-size: 14px;
                           margin-top: 5%;
                           margin-left: 58.5%;
                           margin-bottom: 4%;
                         }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<img src="/var/www/html/$test.png">
<PRE>"
read a 

test=`echo $a | cut -d'=' -f2`

Cluster_data=`cat ClusterFullList.csv | grep -w $test | awk '{print $1" "$2","$12","$13}' > test1.txt`

cat test.txt | sed "s/TITLE/$test/" | sed "s/CLUSTER_NAME.png/$test.png/" | sed "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" > test2.txt 

cat test2.txt | gnuplot
echo "$(sed -n "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" Script_Conso.sh)"

echo "
</PRE>
<PRE>
 <p id="p1">`echo "Consumption difference :"`</p> 
 <p id="p2">`./Script_Conso.sh` </p>

</PRE>
</body>
</html>
"
```

I get the cluster name from the query string with the line :

```
test=`echo $a | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

I generate the file that will be used to make my graph with the line:

```
Cluster_data=`cat ClusterFullList.csv | grep -w $test | awk | {print $1" "$2","$12","$13}' > test1.txt`
```

I change the title of my gnuplot graph and the file that should be used to make the graph with the command sed :

```
cat test.txt | sed "s/TITLE/$test/" | sed "s/CLUSTER_NAME.png/$test.png/" | sed "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" > test2.txt
```

I generate the graph:

```
cat test2.txt | gnuplot
```

I run my script to summarize the consumption:

```
echo "$(sed -n "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" Script_Conso.sh)"
```

Everything works perfectly except the display of the graphic on my web page. The image is well generated in my /var/www/html folder ( I work under RedHat 7.6) but when I look at the source code of the page, the name of my image is".png".

I tested by surrounding my $test variable with { } but it doesn't change anything...

Could you help me?

Thank !

Comment: Why `echo "$(sed -n "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" Script_Conso.sh)"`? Just put `sed -n "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" Script_Conso.sh`

Comment: Also `cat test.txt | sed "..." | sed "..." | sed "..." > test2.txt` can be replaced/simplified by `sed -e "s/TITLE/$test/" -e "s/CLUSTER_NAME.png/$test.png/" -e "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" test.txt > test2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In your second long listing,  $test is referenced for the first time here:

```
<img src="/var/www/html/$test.png">
```

But it is set until 4 lines later here:

```
test=`echo $a | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

If you perform the read a and assignment to test prior to the 'big echo', you should see the image value populated.

In the above statement, the 'big echo' is the long echo which includes the `<html>` tags.

Specifically, I'm talking about the following code:

```
<img src="/var/www/html/$test.png">
<PRE>"
read a 
test=`echo $a | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

In the block above, `a` is used to derive `test`.  As you can see, `test` is referenced before `a` is read.

As an additional suggestion, consider using bash heredoc to provide a template.  I've re-written your first bash script to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF
Content-type: text/html

<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="test/html"; charset=UTF-8">
                <title> CLUSTER GRAPH </title>
                <h1> Cluster Graph <font size=3> <a href="Index.sh">[ Index ]</a> </font> </h1>
                <hr size="4" color="blue">
        </head>
<body>

<p> Choose a Cluster and press the button to generate the graph ! </p>
<form action="script_extract.sh" method="post">
<select name="CLUSTER">
$(
awk '{print $3}' ClusterFullList.csv | sort | uniq | 
while
   read CLUSTER 
do
  echo " <option value="$CLUSTER">$CLUSTER</option>"
done
)
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>

</body>
</html> 
EOF
```

Comment: prior the big echo ?
This echo : echo "$(sed -n "s/CLUSTER_1.txt/test1.txt/" Script_Conso.sh)" ?

the read a and my assignement to test are already before the echo, no ?

Comment: @Makmy - the big echo is the one that includes the <html> tag.